# Globalization decimal type client validation in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

I have an application that is multilingual. I have a simple model like this

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price{ get; set; }
}
```

I set `CurrentCulture` to a culture that has different decimal separator like French `"fr-FR"` (in french decimal separator is `,` ). In my Create Page when I put a number like `655,20` for price I got a javascript validation error that says:

> The field Price must be a number.

When I change CurrentCulture to `en-Us` I can submit my form.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Globalisation Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jquery-globalize/) (globalize.js) which works with jQuery.  Alternatively you can override the `$.validator.methods.number` method to allow an alternative decimal separator For an example [refer this blog](http://blog.rebuildall.net/2011/03/02/jQuery_validate_and_the_comma_decimal_separator).